# Save excel file in a temporary folder in c#

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I have written code to open an excel file. I am interested in saving the excel file in temporary folder automatic once the user has indicated which file to open. This is for my application later on to read the excel and do whatever manipulation with it.
Here is my code below:

```
 private void btnbrowseFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
            openFileDialog1.Title = "Select an Excel file";
            openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"c:\";
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel 97-2007 WorkBook|*.xls|Excel WorkBook|*.xlsx|All Excel Files|*.xls;*.xlsm;*.xlsx";
            openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 3;
            openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                txtFilename.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            }

        }
```

Comment: How do you then open the file? You have to have a reference to Excel.Application, then you can call the method Application.Workbooks.Save and pass it the path to where you want the file to be saved. OTH, Excel saves backup copies of workbooks automatically.

Comment: @martin I want the user to select an excel file which I have to save in my temporary folder. From temp folder I can then manipulate the file by querying it and displaying or inputting the data to a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
{ 
    File.Copy(openFileDialog1.FileName, Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog1.FileName)), true); 
}
```

Comment: I notice the string fileName  is from temporary file name. I wanted the file name from what the user selected.

Comment: @Sithelo Ok, I have edited my answer so it uses the original filename.

Comment: Oh I see, however its likely copying it to same directory or path because its giving me an error that the file exists.

Comment: Hmm, try writing the `GetTempPath` path string to a messagebox to see where it is being saved, then you can check to see.

Comment: Whats happening is the dir is same as fileName, hence the error file already exists.

Comment: Ah right, my mistake, sorry, I am not able to test so I have to write it without a compiler :) Try now, it will get the full path of your selected file and copy it to the temporary path with the filename of the selected file.

Comment: I have edited to  string fileName = Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog1.FileName); and File.Copy(fileName,dir, true);. Its seems to work though the file has to be there in my temp folder to overwrite it.Thats where I am stuck now.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, why do you have to overwrite it?

Comment: I am not overwriting it. When the file is being copied to the temporary  folder an error message pops saying Could not find file 'sample.xls'. this is at File.Copy(fileName, dir, true);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13782/discussion-between-sithelo-and-bali-c)

Answer (score 2):

You can find out the users Temp folder with

```
Path.GetTempPath();
```

And copy it there with `File.Copy();`

work with that file, and when your magic is done, do what you want with it.

Comment: I am realizing I am just a newbie in C#. I have added string tempfolder = Path.GetTempPath(); and File.Copy(sourceFileName, "optic.xls", true); , but my file is not even saved. I haven't yet tried to copy it to my temp. Was testing.